# Android when OnLayout calls?

Tags: android

I developing a custom `View` which extends from `ViewGroup`. It means that i need to implement `onLayout` method. I was think that this method calls when View displays on screen but i think that is not right.

Can you explain me when `onLayout` method calls and what i need implementing in this method?

It make me crash because i see an AdapterView in Android SDK onLayout implementation and that make me confuse because no one parameter in this method not used.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    mLayoutHeight = getHeight();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method do what Javadoc says:

> Called from layout when this view should assign a size and position to
>   each of its children. Derived classes with children should override
>   this method and call layout on each of their children.

So in other words go through your view's children and set their positions and sizes. In reference documentation of `ViewGroup.java` which you are extending there is a nice [example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

There is also a [training](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) for creating custom views on Android Developers Site.