# When scroll the ListView, why onLayout method not called in ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Write a Custom ListView like:

```
public class MyListView extends ListView {
    public MyListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        Log.d("onLayout","onLayout=====");
    }
}
```

As I know, when the layout attribute of view has changed, in order to apply the change ( invalide()  or  requestLayout() )，its parent's onLayout method should be called and layout its children.

So when I scroll the ListView, the layout attribute of its child view has changed, but onLayout doesn't called at all. Why?

Comment: check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471906/android-when-onlayout-calls

Comment: Presumably because scrolling doesn't change the _layout_, only the portion of the ListView that is visible, so you don't (shouldn't) need to re-layout the children. Changing the _size_ that the list view occupies _would_ call onLayout as this _would_ usually need the layout of the children to be recalculated.

Comment: Please note the scrolling a list view doesn't change it's bound. Try adding a view beneath a view and toggle visibility of that view to see the `onLayout` getting call.

Comment: But  javadoc says:

Called from layout when this view should assign a size and position to each of its children. Derived classes with children should override this method and call layout on each of their children.

Although ListView desnt't change it's bound,but it  do change its chlldren's positon.So as the javadoc says,it will call layout().--> onLayout()?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I realized relayout a ViewGroup don't need always call onLayout()/layout() method.There are many ways to change views position in ViewGroup,but each way must call onDraw() to write the changed position in FrameBuffer in order to show it in Screen.(Please tell whether I'm wrong with this)
In ListView,I had debug the source code,and when scroll ListView, the stack trace is:
`

```
trackMotionScroll:5023, AbsListView (android.widget) 
scrollIfNeeded:3424, AbsListView (android.widget) 
startScrollIfNeeded:3352, AbsListView (android.widget) 
onTouchMove:3793, AbsListView (android.widget) 
onTouchEvent:3651, AbsListView (android.widget) 
dispatchTouchEvent:9294, View (android.view)
```

in trackMotionScroll,it will call ViewGroup#offsetChildrenTopAndBottom(incrementalDeltaY)

```
public void offsetChildrenTopAndBottom(int offset) {
    final int count = mChildrenCount;
    final View[] children = mChildren;
    boolean invalidate = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View v = children[i];
        v.mTop += offset;
        v.mBottom += offset;
        if (v.mRenderNode != null) {
            invalidate = true;
            v.mRenderNode.offsetTopAndBottom(offset);
        }
    }

    if (invalidate) {
        invalidateViewProperty(false, false);
    }
    notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChangedIfNeeded();
}
```

This will cause the reLayout of ListView.
So I got a conclusion,you don't need obey the framework's measure()–layout()–draw() procedure,but only change view's layout attribute and invalidate,it will also change view's layout. 
And I guess ListView dispense with layout() when scroll will improve its efficiency